# Copy and paste the data into new worksheet which is compared from source and target

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros, please help me in the below scenario issue

**Scenario**

1. Compare two excel sheets columns(Source Sheet & Target Sheet) and put the reult in a different sheet(Result Sheet).

NOTE - Columns selection from source and target are dynamic

1. Input the Colum names which you want to include in Result sheet in addition to Source & target Column. ( e.g include column B, C, D , F (from source sheet)  also  in result sheet.

**Issue**

Below is my script,the issue is while pasting the dynamic selected column from source to result sheet it is pasting the data in column which are given input in source.
*Example* - while pasting the C,G,F from source to result sheet it is pasting the data in columns C,G,F of result instead pasting in the next empty column(B,C,D).

In the below script "Worksheets("Result").Cells(Rownum, ch) = Column_source_value" is causing this issue, please help me how i need to change Cells parameters

**Code**

```
Dim ws1lastrow As Long, ws2lastrow As Long, ws1lastcolumn As Integer, ws2lastcolumn As Integer
Dim maxRow As Integer, maxColumn As Integer  
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, x As Long, Column_source As String, Column_target As String
Dim sourceValue As String
Dim targetvalue As String
Dim addsourcecolvalue As String, ch As Variant, AddColumn_source_num As String, AddColumn_source_value As String
Dim addsourceValue() As String

Sub Compare()
CompareWorksheets Worksheets("Source"), Worksheets("Target")
End Sub

Sub CompareWorksheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
sourceValue = Sheets("Source").TextBox1.Value
targetvalue = Sheets("Source").TextBox2.Value
addsourcecolvalue = Sheets("Source").TextBox3.Value

With ws1.UsedRange
    ws1lastrow = .Rows.Count
    ws1lastcolumn = .Columns.Count
End With

With ws2.UsedRange
    ws2lastrow = .Rows.Count
    ws2lastcolumn = .Columns.Count
End With

maxRow = ws1lastrow
maxColumn = ws1lastcolumn

For i = 1 To ws1lastrow
    For j = 1 To ws2lastrow
        Column_source_num = sourceValue & i
        Column_target_num = targetvalue & j
        Column_source_value = Worksheets("Source").Range(Column_source_num).Value
        Column_target_value = Worksheets("Target").Range(Column_target_num).Value
        If Column_source_value = Column_target_value Then
            Sheets("Source").Cells.Find(What:=Column_source_value, LookAt:=xlWhole,   MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            Dim Rownum As String
            Rownum = ActiveCell.Row
            Worksheets("Result").Cells(i, 1) = Column_source_value
            splitsourcecloumn (Rownum)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub

Function splitsourcecloumn(Rownum)
addsourceValue() = Split(addsourcecolvalue, ",")

For Each ch In addsourceValue()
    Column_source_num = ch & Rownum
    Column_source_value = Worksheets("Source").Range(Column_source_num).Value
    Worksheets("Result").Cells(Rownum, ch) = Column_source_value
Next ch
End Function
```

Comment: Just a quick observation here: inside your double i/j `for` loop, you dimension `Rownum` as a `String` rather than a `Long`. Even if that is the correct data type, `Rownum` strongly indicates a number rather than text, so I would suggest taking a closer look there

Comment: You never look for the "next free column" on the Result sheet, you are passing a number you are defining based on the range you have gotten from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function to find the first unused column.

```
Public Function GetLastColumn() As Long
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
    GetLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
    After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
End If
End Function
```

I hope this helps!